# safari extension to download pdf file without opening it in browser

Tags: safari, safari-extension

I have developed a Firefox extension to download a PDF file directly without opening it in the browser. and now I want to develop same extension for safari but I am new to safari extension development so please help me, with the basics of safari extension development 
so far I have done the following steps:-

1. Installed safari
2. Generated certificate and installed
3. Made a simple safari extension and tested.

You can also check my Firefox extension for reference.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/direct-pdf-download/

Comment: Any news on that? Did you manage to do it?